# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: importtsv

Tags: hbase, cloudera-cdh

I am trying to load a csv file to Hbase table using bulkloader utility and receiving below error continuously. I did search in the site for effective answer but failed to find so.

I am not sure about what exactly value the env variables $HBASE_HOME and $HADOOP_CLASSPATH should contain in CDH 5.4 VM.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: importtsv
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:214)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck with the above problem for a while but, have my luck at working solution for it. Basically I've set
*$HBASE_HOME=/usr/lib/hbase*

and from home dir do following:
*/usr/bin/hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.ImportTsv*

Thus, I get to load the csv files to Hbase tables directly! :)